# SublimeLinter not detecting my Node.js installation (Debian)

Tags: debian, sublimetext2, sublimelinter

I'm running Debian Squeeze and I've installed node.js with nvm.

I'm sourcing nvm.sh from .bashrc and set my version as default:

```
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Running `node` from the terminal works, but SublimeLinter doesn't seems to detect it:

```
SublimeLinter: javascript disabled (One of the following JavaScript engines must be installed: node.js, JavaScriptCore)
```

I created a symbolic link at `/opt/bin` (which is in my PATH):

```
$ cd /opt/bin
$ ln -s ~/.nvm/v0.10.3/bin/node
```

Still the same issue.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

At the command prompt, run `which node`, then open `Preferences -> Package Settings -> SublimeLinter -> Settings - User` and set it to the following (assuming there are no other contents):

```
{
    "sublimelinter_executable_map":
    {
        "node": "/opt/bin/node" // put results of 'which node' here
    }
}
```

Also, remember that you need to have [gjslint](https://developers.google.com/closure/utilities/docs/linter_howto) set up on your system (if that's the linter you want) before it will work. JSHint and JSLint are built-in, and are set by adjusting the `javascript_linter` option.